# How to create a Show Hide Nav Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a show hide Nav menu like this..

http://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/inspiration/22-fresh-single-page-website-for-your-inspiration

---

### HTML Code

```
<div id="menus">
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
<li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
<li><a href="#">WRITINGS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

---

### CSS Code

```
#nav ul{
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding:50px;
}
#nav ul li{
float:left;
padding:48px;

}
#nav a:link{
color:#999;
}
#nav a:visited{
color:#000;
}
#nav a:hover{
color:#999;
border-bottom-style:solid;
}
```

---

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2):

We can just change the `top` property of the `ul` links make it to default to a minus value eq `top:-70px;` then when we hover the `header` make the `ul` top value `0` by adding a class called `show` via jquery.

Here is the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpPZKe)

The main code we have to worry about is the `ul` and `header` properties

HTML:

```
  <header> 
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

CSS:

```
ul {

 -webkit-transition:all 0.6s;
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
}
.show {
  top: 0;
}
```

(the transition is gonna make it a smooth animation instead of showing immediately)

JS:

```
$("header").hover(function() {
  $('ul.menu').toggleClass('show')
})
```